# Getting TypeError: rowModel is undefined on particular pages in mui datagrid

Tags: reactjs, pagination, next.js13, mui-x-data-grid

I am working on nextjs project where i have used the mui datagrid. I have customized the pagination component of datagrid and i am using server side pagination.
Following are the code snippets related to pagination from the code.

```
function CustomPagination() {
    const apiRef = useGridApiContext();
    const page = useGridSelector(apiRef, gridPageSelector);
    const pageCount = useGridSelector(apiRef, gridPageCountSelector);

    return (
      <Pagination
        color="primary"
        variant="outlined"
        shape="rounded"
        page={page + 1}
        count={Math.ceil(rowCountState / 10)}
        renderItem={(props2) => <PaginationItem {...props2} disableRipple />}
        onChange={(event, value) => {
          apiRef.current.setPage(value - 1);
          setPaginationModel({ ...paginationModel, page: value - 1 });
        }}
      />
    );
  }

const fetchData= () => {
    refetch();
  };
```

```
  <DataGrid
        rows={substanceRowData}
        columns={columns}
        loading={isLoading}
        disableRowSelectionOnClick
        paginationMode="server"
        rowCount={rowCountState}
        onPaginationModelChange={() => fetchData()}
        slots={{
          pagination: CustomPagination,
        }}
/>
```

rowCountState is total number of records that are returned by API (approx 30k), refetch() inside fetchData() is from useQuery.
My solution is working as expected but on pages 9, 15, and some other pages i get error
"TypeError: rowModel is undefined on particular pages in mui datagrid".

Expected outcome : pagination to work properly as working on other pages but on certain random pages getting error

```
TypeError: rowModel is undefined on particular pages in mui datagrid
```

Thank you in advance for help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `rowModel` to the DataGrid component.
In your case, it would look like this:

```
<DataGrid
  rows={substanceRowData}
  columns={columns}
  loading={isLoading}
  disableRowSelectionOnClick
  paginationMode='server'
  rowModel ='server' // Add this line.
  rowCount={rowCountState}
  onPaginationModelChange={() => fetchData()}
  slots={{
    pagination: CustomPagination
  }}
/>
```

Comment: For me adding rowModel ='server' didn't work. On another component I have used similar logic and no error is thrown there. I suppose it might be something related to data from API.